# Could you please recommend some books that compile essays/prose written before 1950 by famous philosophers like Hume, Sartre, Voltaire, and others?

Tags: essay

Can you recommend to me some books that compile essays or prose on different topics (e.g., freedom, free will, enlightenment) written by famous philosophers like Hume, Sartre, Voltaire, and others? Essays that were written before the 20th century.

I have googled a lot but can't seem to find any books. Most of the books I found are essays written by more recent scholars. It would be really helpful if someone please recommend some books. Thanks.